# passing a tuple as variable

Tags: python, class, arguments

I am passing a tuple by argument, i get the following error.
I searched on the internet and the working method was correct. Can someone have a look?

Person class

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqldata import Sqldata


class Person:
    def __init__(self, addr, client):
        self.addr = "192.12"
        self.client = "demorun"
        self.name = none

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name
        values = (self.addr, self.name, str(datetime.now()))
        Sqldata.create_connclient(values)
```

Sqldata class to write data to the database,

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
import os

fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename = "dbConnClients.db"
db_file = os.path.join(fileDir,  "database\\" + filename)


class Sqldata:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = None
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        except Error as e:
            print(e)

    def create_connclient(self, vdata):
        print(vdata)
        conn = self.conn
        sqlquery = ''' SELECT id FROM ConnClients WHERE name = ? '''
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sqlquery, vdata[1])
```

Error:

```
File "...person.py", line 23, in set_name
    Sqldata.create_connclient(vdata)
TypeError: create_connclient() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vdata'
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming Sqldata is a class you have created (hesitant due to the lack of that particular code and proper indentation).  Because it is a class, it needs to be instantiated prior to calling it's methods.

I am not sure why you made it a class if you are going to call it anonymously but the below is the solution:

```
Sqldata().create_connclient(values)
# if your __init__ function has args,
# you will need to input it in the instantiation
```

What this means is that we have just created an instance of the class object `Sqldata`. `create_connclient` has two parameters, `self` and `vdata`. By calling `Sqldata()`, you just created a `self` value when you call `create_connclient` and you satisfy all required parameters (as shown in the error).

The Sqldata class is correctly initiated.

```
class Sqldata:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = None
        ...
```

It is the TypeError which indicates my class method does not accept the tuple. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the two values in the tuple as the two arguments `self` and `vdata`, you should write it like this.

```
Sqldata.create_connclient(*values)
```

The asterisk unpacks the tuple. However, please read justahuman's response, since I think they may have spotted a deeper issue.